# Jackson XmlMapper: Custom Deserializer XML child node structure as string

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I would like to deserialize an XML subtree as string (with Jackson) in JAVA:

input structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <nodeA>text</nodeA>
  <nodeB>
    <nodeS>
      <nodeS1>...</nodeS1>
      <nodeS2>...</nodeS2>
    </nodeS>
  </nodeB>
</root>
```

into something like this:

```
public class Pojo {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="nodeA")
  private String nodeA; // = "text"
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="nodeB")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = MyXmlDeserializer.class)
  private String nodeB; // = "<nodeS><nodeS1>...</nodeS1><nodeS2>...</nodeS2></nodeS>"
}
```

The node **nodeS** should be taken as "raw-value" without ANY modifications to the xml and put it into a String class member.
I've tried it with custom deserializer or as @JacksonRawValue with no avail.

if one just could access the raw value of the "currentNode", that would help a lot.

Any alternative (jackson-related) solutions welcome :-)

Comment: Why would you think that a **JSON** deserializer would have any impact on parsing **XML**?

Comment: @Andreas: I'm using XmlMapper (jackson-dataformat-xml)

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a workaround rather than a solution, but it's possible to use XmlMapper inside your JsonDeserializer:

```
xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
```

As a result you'll get Xml string again. But as I wrote, it's workaround and I don't like it gets from Xml to Json, and from Json to Xml again.

If anyone get a better solution (using Jackson), please share.